# How to Get rowID in rowattr block of jqgrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, performance, jqgrid

I am having jqgrid this way,

```
    <div id="dialogLoading" style="position:absolute;z-index:1005">
        <img src="http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/InternetSlowdown_Day.gif" />
    </div>
    <table id="list"></table>

    $(function () {
    var blueArray = [];
        for (var i=1;i<=4000;i++) {
          blueArray.push(i);
        }   
    var greenArray = [];
        for (var i=4000;i<=6000;i++) {
          greenArray.push(i);
        }   

    var redArray = [];
        for (var i=6000;i<=8000;i++) {
          redArray.push(i);
        } 
    var yellowArray = [];
        for (var i=8000;i<=10000;i++) {
          yellowArray.push(i);
        }   


    "use strict";
        var getGridData = function(n) {
                var data = [], i;
                for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                    data.push({
                        id: (i + 1)*10,
                        aa: "aa" + i,      // colunn 1
                        bb: "bb" + (i%3),  // colunn 2
                        cc: "cc" + (i%5),  // colunn 3
                        dd: "dd" + (i%7),  // colunn 4
                        ee: "ee" + (i%11), // colunn 5
                        ff: "ff" + (i%13), // colunn 6
                        gg: "gg" + (i%17), // colunn 7
                        hh: "hh" + (i%19), // colunn 8
                        ii: "ii" + (i%23), // colunn 9
                        jj: "jj" + (i%29), // colunn 10
                        kk: "kk" + (i%31), // colunn 11
                        ll: "ll" + (i%37), // colunn 12
                        mm: "mm" + (i%41)  // colunn 13
                    });
                }
                return data;
            },
            $grid = $("#list"),
            gridData,
            startTime,
            measureTime = false,
            timeInterval;

        gridData = getGridData(10000);
        startTime = new Date();
        $grid.jqGrid({
            data: gridData,
            colModel: [
                { name: "aa", label: "c01" },
                { name: "bb", label: "c02" },
                { name: "cc", label: "c03" },
                { name: "dd", label: "c04" },
                { name: "ee", label: "c05" },
                { name: "ff", label: "c06" },
                { name: "gg", label: "c07" },
                { name: "hh", label: "c08" },
                { name: "ii", label: "c09" },
                { name: "jj", label: "c10" },
                { name: "kk", label: "c11" },
                { name: "ll", label: "c12" },
                { name: "mm", label: "c13" }
            ],
            cmTemplate: { width: 100, autoResizable: true },
            iconSet: "fontAwesome",
            rowNum: 10000,
            rownumWidth: 40,
            //rowList: [20, 100, 1000, 10000, "100000:All"],
            viewrecords: true,
            rownumbers: true,
            //toppager: true,
            //pager: true,
            shrinkToFit: false,
            rowattr: function (rd) {           
            var rowIds = $("#list").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
            console.log(rowIds);
if(blueArray.indexOf(rowIds) > -1)
            return {"class": "blue"}
           else if(greenArray.indexOf(rowIds) > -1)           
            return {"class": "green"}
            else if(redArray.indexOf(rowIds) > -1)
            return {"class": "yellow"}
            else
            return {"class": "one"}
                },        
            loadComplete: function () {
                closeDialogLoading();
                if (measureTime) {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        alert("Total loading time: " + timeInterval + "ms");
                    }, 50);
                    measureTime = false;
                }            
            },
            autoencode: true,
            caption: "Shows the performance of resizing. Make double-click on the column resizer"
        }).jqGrid("gridResize");

        timeInterval = new Date() - startTime;
        setTimeout(function () {
            alert("Total time: " + timeInterval + "ms");
        }, 50);

        function openDialogLoading(){
            $("#dialogLoading").css("display", "");
        }

        function closeDialogLoading(){
            $("#dialogLoading").hide();
        }
    });
```

## css:

```
.one { background:red; }
.blue { background:blue; }
.green { background:green; }
.yellow { background:yellow; }
```

I am trying to chaNge the row color of the jqgrid comparing each rowid with an array of values.

Here is the logic for that,

```
    rowattr: function (rd) {           
            var rowIds = $("#list").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
            console.log(rowIds);
if(blueArray.indexOf(rowIds) > -1)
            return {"class": "blue"}
           else if(greenArray.indexOf(rowIds) > -1)           
            return {"class": "green"}
            else if(redArray.indexOf(rowIds) > -1)
            return {"class": "yellow"}
            else
            return {"class": "one"}
```

the problem here is, rowIds  are getting as empty []. so always my condition i going to else and red color is shown on each row's.

I need to check if rowid is exists in blueArray,greenArray  e.t.c  if its is true paint that row with the corresponding color.

In my example my bluearray has values from 1 to 4000. So all these records from 1 to 4000 have to be painted in blue.

My logic inside rowattr: block is not working as i am getting rowid as empty[].

How to get rowid inside rowattr: function (rd) {}  block of jqrid?

The above logic working is fine in loadcomplete and gridcomplete events but it is blocking entire ui and taking hell lot of time to load grid.

Can anyone help me in this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need just use `rd.id` inside of `rowattr`:

```
rowattr: function (rd) {
    if (blueArray.indexOf(rd.id) > -1) {
        return {"class": "blue"};
    } else if (greenArray.indexOf(rd.id) > -1) {
        return {"class": "green"};
    } else if (redArray.indexOf(rd.id) > -1) {
        return {"class": "red"};
    } else {
        return {"class": "one"};
    }
}
```

[the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/performane-13-10000-10000-free-jqgrid-RGB.htm) uses the code, but it's really slowly because you create 13x10000 cells in the grid. I recommend to open the demo only in Chrome where it takes still about 15 sec.

I strictly recommend to use local paging. Look at [almost the same demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/performane-13-10000-25-free-jqgrid-RGB.htm) where the page size is 25 instead of absolute unneeded 10000. It works really quickly. One can jump on the page 200 or 300 to see another colors.

Comment: following the local paging approach as you suggested.But can we override any event in JQGRID and show loader while 10000 records are shown? as it is hanging the browser for some ms until all 10000 records are shown?

Comment: @user1660325: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. "can we override any event"??? The demo **generate the test data** first. The demo don't use Promise which could do some work in another thread. It **simulate** loading in very simple way. So one should **ignore** the first part. If you want be more close to reality you should generate JSON data and place the data in file and to use ´datatype: "json", loadonce: true´. You can host the file on the server, which supports gzip for static files and HTTP/2 algorithm. Then you can look like the web browser of your choice loads the data.

Comment: @user1660325: In any way, local paging is **really must to do** for me. One should don't use it only if one want to make the web page 100-1000 times slowly as it could be.

Comment: I have used local paging as you suggested and this is working fine perfectly.. http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/performane-13-10000-25-free-jqgrid-RGB.htm..But the problem is when i have selected All in the pagination combo box.. as the data is larg. its taking 40 to 50 sec to load 1000 records and the entire page is hanging..

Comment: SO for that 40 to 50 sec to load all (10000) records.... instead of hanging the browser can we show some gif image showing processing..?

Comment: i mean to say can we show loading progress like... 'loading data of 10000 records' on clicking the pagination combo box?

Comment: is there any way to show processing gif on selecting 1000/ 2000/ 3000 on the pagination combo box?